# If I link some specific words on my website to Wikipedia will it increase site SEO?

Tags: seo, ranking

Possible if it's duplicate (however didn't got my answer when searching on this community)

Example: I create a hyperlink for my word 'Earth' to Wikipedia's earth's definition will it improve my SEO?

Comment: I don't think so, otherwise, we would all already be doing it.

Comment: Just in case it acts like a backlink?

Comment: Backlink is when they link back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Is it beneficial to your visitors?

If quoting Wikipedia and providing a link is beneficial by all means do it. Google has advanced to the point where it, (or at least it is believed it), can get a hint as to how useful the page was to the users.

### About keywords in links

Google has an excess of 200 ranking factors, and Keywords in links is an old algo, for onpage SEO. Although it **is a fundamental method for determining what documents are about**. Not to far down the list from title, headings ... links to other related pages ... is the word used in text?

I believe the algo for keywords in links may be best understood if one goes back in time to the turn of the millennium literally the 2000s before Google when Altavista and Excite were the main search engines. And people were stuffing keywords as the number of times a keyword is used was part of how sites were rated.

> To prevent keyword stuffing changes were made to rate sites by a more
> natural text usage of a keyword or percent. IE for some material a
> keyword may be natural at 2% usage so an excess or 10% usage was to
> high and deemed unnatural and spammy. But links were excluded from
> keyword stuffing prevention algos.
>
> So sites could get listed first by having a section of links for the
> same keyword to external and internal pages. Some were also cloaking a page for search engines providing them a list of links and giving other material to the visitor.

So linking to the Wikipedia page about "earth" tells search that the page is about earth ... as does having an h1, h2, h3, h4; having an image with an alt property of earth; having a video about the earth on the page; etc. But the link would be excluded from being counted as keyword stuffing.

Although over the last 20 years great improvements have been made in having algos determine the subject of written material. AI is near the point of being able to have a conversation with people.

Additional on-page consideration is how much of the above-the-fold information on the page relates to earth? does word also appear in the text of is this link a one off?

### The testing for keyword link impact

How to determine how much impact having keyword links has in a current search engine result page? There are many great resources on the internet where the content is made from materials on other sites ... IE "10 best graphic editors" ... these sites would represent the canary in the coal mine as to how much effect that particular algo has ... subject to change at the next re-indexing.

If I may add some of my own experience?

I tend to cite materials (make **a bibliography**) I have read in some documents. I've not seen any noticeable improvement for search engines on these pages, for quiet a while. Although Wikipedia is a good test case for how well this works.

If it worked well everyone would add a bibliography to their pages.

I also have made a number of directories for specific vertical niches, in the past, they did quite well, but I've not seen any of this directory style of pages work as they did in the past for a long time.

**I for one would be glad to do more archival linking to great content on the internet if Google would do more to promote that type of content.**

Comment: Congrats on reaching 1K reputation points Wayne, you're doing a great job here with really detailed & quality answers!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know and experienced it, Google respects giving backlinks to other sources (especially to the source you may have used in your content) so it may make a difference.

BEST practices for this would be the following:

1. Not draining all of your page authority by linking to many sources(at most 2 outgoing links seems good).
2. Don't implement this outgoing links on every page and content.
3. Try to link to authoritative pages like known wikies, university or government websites or MOZ/Semrush high authority ones.

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience in SEO, I don't think such tricks would work, and the best example is that search engine or Google Algorithm also looks for backlinks, not only words, like,
If you type "Earth" then if your website backlinks are more than Wikipedia then Google would pick your website, or if your website backlinks DA, PA, are higher than the Wikipedia Backlinks, then Google would pick your website, otherwise, you have to compete via Quality content then Wikipedia.